# Crawls-Mail fails to enter e-mail address when associated nickname is typed in address field

Tags: email

2014-11-29

I installed Crawls-Mail recently and subsequently created an address book complete with 
addresses and nicknames. But Crawls-Mail does not show any e-mail address when I type a nickname in the address field. This forces me to click on an address in the address book if I don't want to type it in the message's address window.

I'll appreciate any help in fixing this problem.

Julianloui
to open the address book

Answer (score 0):

In the address field, after typing nickname, press `Tab` and there will be list of emails matching nickname from your address book.